# Nested ng-repeat with dynamic input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a JSON response in a table using ng-repeat. The problem is that not all objects recieved are the same. All of them have a date, short message and long message. There are also ones with an additional value list, differing in length. This list should be diplayed underneath the long message within its own table or list. I use the `alert.slice().reverse()` because I want the newest entries to be on top. The new objects are inserted using `.push({values})`.

```
<tbody class="AlTbody" ng-repeat="alerts in alerts.slice().reverse()" ng-class="className">
    <tr class="Altr Aldate">
        <td ng-show="{{alerts.Date}}"><b>{{alerts.Date}}:</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Altr Alshort " ng-click="toggleDetail($index)">
        <td>{{alerts.S}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Altr " ng-show="activePosition == $index">
        <td class="msgL">{{alerts.L}}
            <!-- 1)  <p ng-show="{{item.List}}"><br><ul><li>Previous values:</li> <li ng-repeat="vals in ValueList">{{vals.value}}</li></ul> </p>-->
            <!-- 2)  <p ng-show="{{List.txt}}"> <br><ul><li>Previous values:</li> <li ng-repeat="List in alerts.List">{{List.txt}}</li></ul> </p>-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I already tried two approaches as seen in the code. The first one displayed the list correct however it was displayed underneath every long message instead of only the one it belongs to. I used a new variable.

```
var l=valList.length;
scope.List=true;
while(l>-1){
    scope.ValueList.push({value: valList[l]});
    l--;
}
```

The second approach did not work at all because I could not find an index.

```
 var l=valList.length;
       var indexV= jQuery.inArray(currdate,scope.alerts.Date);
        while(l>-1){  
          scope.alerts[indexV].List.push({txt: valList[l]});
            l--;
        }
```

edit:
This is the current [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo3oA.png). There you can see two objects( date, short message and long message) and both of them have the previous values section. However only the upper object is supposed to diplay the list of previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is entirely possible, my advice is to start at a known point and work from there.

I have put together a jsfiddle to show you how nested ng-repeats will work. try and work from that point. As a side note it looks like your JSON structure is overly complex, if you can simplify that down I would.

https://jsfiddle.net/roscorcoran/wyu7tgxm/

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
    <a ng-if="alert.Date">{{alert.Date}}</a>

    <p ng-repeat="val in alert.L.vals">
      <a ng-if="val && val.value">{{val.value}}</a>
    </p>

    <p ng-repeat="item in alert.List">
      <a ng-if="item && item.txt">{{item.txt}}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this also work when the object is not predifenied and more are added throuout the run of the programm? The JSON structure is this complex because I recieve "alerts" one alert contains a date a short message and a long message. Some alerts also contain a list of values. I don't know any way of simplifying this. I also added the output to my question.

Comment: Yes if the scope model is modified asynchronously then it should update on the view/template also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `ng-if` statement inside the ng-repeat loop:

```
<p ng-if="{{values.list}}"><br><ul><li>Previous values:</li> <li ng-repeat="vals in values.list">{{vals.value}}</li></ul> </p>-->
```

Comment: It stills displays the values underneath every long message.

Comment: I don't quite get your question then, could you make a sample output? Additionally, when and to what do you set "activePosition" ?
By the way, you can order a collection in angular's ng-repeat with
"| orderBy : expression : reverse" (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: I added the output in my question. The activePosition is useed to displaay the long message if the user clicks on the short one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this works for me now. It still always displays "Previous Values:" but the values only display when they actually belong to the message.

```
<ul ng-if="alerts.List.vals"><li>Previous values:</li> <li ng-repeat="val in alerts.List.vals" >{{val.value}}</li></ul>
```

This might not be the best and most elegant solution but it works.

```
if(valList){
         scope.alerts.push({Date:currdate,S:msgSn,L:msgLn, List:{ vals:[{value:valList[0]},{value:valList[2]},{value:valList[4]},{value:valList[6]}] } });
    }else{
         scope.alerts.push({Date:currdate,S:msgSn,L:msgLn });
    }
```

I only display the even indexes of the value array because the list of values was a string which I split and every uneven entry is "):" which I don't need to display.

Comment: you have to be careful when doing this: you impicitly assume that the array contains at least 7 entries, you may check this before and handle accordingly...
So do I get that correctly, only the even indexes of the array have these "previous values"? if yes, you could do: <li ng-if="$index%2==0">Previous Values:</li>